# ISTQB question: Statement and Decision coverage

Tags: manual-testing, interview, coverage, istqb

```
READ A
READ B
READ C
IF C>A THEN
IF C>B THEN
PRINT "C must be smaller bla bla.."
ELSE
PRINT "Proceed to next stage"
ENDIF
ELSE
PRINT "B CAN BE SMALLER THEN C"
ENDIF
```

Could someone explain to me the logic of calculating the number of statement and branch coverage (MINIMUM for both) for this task. I thought I understand these sort of tasks but this one got me stuck actually.

Answer (score 2):

This becomes more readable with indentation:

```
READ A
READ B
READ C
IF C>A THEN
    IF C>B THEN
        PRINT "C must be smaller bla bla.."
    ELSE
        PRINT "Proceed to next stage"
    ENDIF
ELSE
    PRINT "B CAN BE SMALLER THEN C"
ENDIF
```

Statement coverage requires each statement to be executed, whereas branch coverage requires each branch (or decision) to be executed.

Usually, 100% branch coverage implies 100% statement coverage, but not necessarily vice versa. However, in this example both `IF`s have `ELSE` branches and, therefore, you have to execute all branches to reach each statement.

An example where statement coverage is not the same as branch coverage:

```
READ X
READ Y
IF X > Y
    X = X + 1
ENDIF
PRINT X
```

Here, statement coverage doesn't have to cover the case where `X` is smaller or equals `Y`—such that the line `X = X + 1` isn't executed—which would be required with branch coverage.

If you are struggling with these questions, consider drawing a flow chart as shown, e.g., here: [How to calculate Statement, Branch/Decision and Path Coverage for ISTQB Exam purpose](https://istqb.guru/how-to-calculate-statement-branchdecision-and-path-coverage-for-istqb-exam-purpose/)